# windows batch | for loop and dir command with parameter

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, parameters

Working command - pasted directly in command shell:

```
for /f %a in ('dir /b /s ..\*') do @echo %~na | findstr transport_bb_*_*_* | sort
```

Problem 1) The same command executed from a .bat file results in an error:

```
| was unexpected at this time.
```

Problem 2) In addition, would like the mentioned .bat file to accept a parameter (directory):

```
for /f %a in ('dir /b /s %1\..\*') do @echo %~na | findstr transport_bb_*_*_* | sort
```

Tried apostrophes, "grave accents", double percents, using SET to put whole command inside parenthesis, still no effect.

Help appreciated.

Thanks,
Bart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ad 1) In batch file you have to double the `%` -> `%%`. The pipes `|` you will have to replace with workflow:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /F "delims=" %%A in ('dir /B /S ..\*') do (
    echo %~nA
    set "search_in_file=%%A"
    findstr transport_bb_*_*_* !search_in_file! | sort
)
```

ad 2) Take in user input

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL  ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "input=%~1"
SET "search_in_dir=!input!\*"

   for /F "delims=" %%A in ('dir /B /S !search_in_dir!') do (
        REM echo %%~nA
        set "search_in_file=%%A"
        REM ECHO findstr "transport_bb_*_*_*" "%search_in_file%"
        findstr "transport_bb_*_*_*" "!search_in_file!"
        IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
           ECHO "String NOT found in file !search_in_file!"
        ) ELSE (
           ECHO ""String found in file !search_in_file!"
        )
    )
```

or more like your script:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "input=%~1"
SET "search_in_dir=!input!\*"

   for /F "delims=" %%A in ('dir /B /S !search_in_dir!') do (
        set "search_in_file=%%A"
        findstr /M "transport_bb_*_*_*" "!search_in_file!" | sort
    )
```

**Notes:**

Where findstr parameter:

```
/M         Prints only the filename if a file contains a match.
```

`%~1` ... takes in first user parameter and expands it
`!....!` now delimits a variable due to `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` being enabled.